# Laravel4 Pagination Issue

Tags: laravel-4, pagination

```
$dbDetails= Contract::where( 'a', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'b', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'c', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'd', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->paginate($paginationNumber);
```

This is my controller and am getting the pagination links in view by using

```
{{ $contractDetails->appends(array('search' => 'test'))->links() }}
```

So here is how my url looks like

```
domain.com/search?page=2&search=test
```

Iam wondering how can i get the second page with 10 number of rows?

Can anyone help me to solve this?
Thanks in advance

Comment: try:


return \Paginator::make($dbDetails, $dbDetails->count(), 10);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say pas the value 10 as a get parameter, read it and pass it to `paginate->()`.

```
$dbDetails= Contract::where( 'a', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'b', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'c', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->orWhere( 'd', 'LIKE', "%$searchText%" )
            ->paginate(Input::get('paginate'));
```

This is my controller and am getting the pagination links in view by using

```
{{ $contractDetails->appends(array('search' => 'test', 'paginate' => 10))->links() }}
```

So here is how my url should look like

```
domain.com/search?page=2&search=test&paginate=10
```

If I understand correctly this is what u want.